# Kernel panic — not syncing: Oops. Как определить причину?

Tags: kernel

Сервер вообщем работает стабильно несколько лет. Но вот за этот год падал с этой ошибкой -Kernel panic — not syncing: Oops. Помогите определить причину? Грешить на что-то конкретно не могу.

[image: Все что смог сфоткать с экрана.]

Comment: а что говорит `syslog`? Можете добавить какие-то подробности

Comment: syslog пуст, точнее syslogd: -- MARK -- а дальше syslogd 1.4.1: restart.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/92946/cannot-boot-because-kernel-panic-not-syncing-attempted-to-kill-init

Comment: Не, не тот случай.

Comment: Какой-то Ваш ресурс? похоже он лежит

Comment: Это я скриншот выложил на яндекс диск. Ссылка работает, проверил.

Comment: а... в Украине яндекс забанили:)

Comment: тут не знаю, будем ждать более компитентных участников, может стоит продублировать вопрос на `ask.ubuntu`?

Comment: Данных не достаточно. перед kernel panic обычно полэкрана, если не больше, полезной информации в том числе и с указанием реальных причин. по возможности приложите все сообщения. причем в тексте самого вопроса (ссылка "править" под вопросом)

Comment: Добавил скриншот, но больше сфоткать не смог.